# HUD loader do not show properly in UITabelViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, load

I'm using HUD loader to show the process.
I have a view controller which embedded UITabelViewController using container (refer image)[image].

On click of a button, i need to call API , But UITabelViewController cuts the HUD Loader (refer image)[image].
What to do ?

Thank you.

Comment: try this one [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tableView];

Comment: I already tried it , but it didn't help !

Comment: hi you got your solution?

Comment: Actually I've tried several ways like you said and one which i listed below, but i wanna know that if there is any other proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the HUD loader takes UIviewController's view,
your UITabelViewController contains height more than screen height,
So it gets confused.

Solution :

```
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: false)
```

Scroll your Tabel view to the top and then add the loader it will work perfectly.

Thank you